# Making an array smaller with realloc, losing first element

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I've been trying to make an example program using calloc and realloc and I've come across an issue where, when I make an array of integers smaller, it seems to remove the first element instead of the last one.

```
int *m = (int*)calloc(2, sizeof(int));

    *m = 1;     
    *(m+1) = 2;   
    printf("\tInt 1: %d\n", m[0]);
    printf("\tInt 2: %d\n\n", *(m+1));

// REALLOC

printf("How many elements the array have? ");
scanf("%d", &num);

*m = (int *)realloc(m, num * sizeof(int));

    printf("ARRAY NOW HAS %d PLACES\n\n\t", num);

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        m[i] = i + 1;
        printf("%d ", m[i]);

    }

// DELETING MEMBERS OF AN ARRAY

while((d < 0) || (d > num)) {

    printf("\n\nChoose which position of the previous array should be deleted (0 = first): ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
}

printf("\nUPDATED ARRAY:\n\n");

for(i = d; i < num - 1; i++) {

    m[i] = m[i + 1];
}

*m = (int *)realloc(m, (num - 1)*sizeof(int));

num--;

for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    printf("%d ", m[i]);
}
```

An example of the program output would be:

```
        Int 1: 1
        Int 2: 2

How many elements the array have? 17
ARRAY NOW HAS 17 PLACES

        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

Choose which position of the previous array should be deleted (0 = first): 6

UPDATED ARRAY:

10620272 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

And if I include the last member of the array that should have been deleted (in this case m[16]) it shows:

```
10620272 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 17
```

Of course, I'm not entirely sure what's happening but it seems like it's just removing the value of m[0]?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Also, in `while((d < 0) || (d > num)) {`, `d` does not have a value yet. This should be a `do` statement, not a `while`.

Comment: `*m = (int *)realloc(m, num * sizeof(int));` - again, the compiler surely pointed it out to you, but you just ignored it?

Comment: the variable `d` not defined in the posted code.  the variable `num` not defined in the posted code.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) 3) when calling `realloc`, always assign the returned value to a temp variable, then check (!=NULL)  the temp variable and if not NULL then assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc` fails, the previously allocated memory pointer will be overlayed resulting in a memory leak

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the initial value gets modified is that you are assigning it:

```
*m = (int *)realloc(m, num * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
m = realloc(m, num * sizeof(int));
```

Your code should also produce a warning, telling you that an assignment of a pointer to an array element containing `int`s is invalid. Fixing this warning should have fixed your problem.

Note that an assignment of the form

```
m = realloc(m, ...);
```

where `m` is used on both sides of `realloc` is inherently unsafe, because `realloc` could potentially return `NULL` - for example, when there is not enough memory to allocate. Blind assignment to `m` would render the old value of `m` inaccessible, preventing proper deallocation. In production you should assign `realloc`'s result to a temporary, then check it for `NULL`, and only then assign the result back to `m`.

Comment: The solution was as simple as this! Silly mistake it seems, thank you very much! And thanks to Eric Postpischil too

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296024/2410359) good answer, when reducing the allocation size and the re-allocation fails (a rare event), code can simple continue with the original pointer.

Suggested re-write, assuming `num > 0`:

```
// *m = (int *)realloc(m, num * sizeof(int));
void *t = realloc(m, sizeof *m * num);
if (t) {
  m = t;
}
```